# Map Google Drive to Network Drive (Without Download)

Tags: windows-10, google-drive

I'm on a university computer and don't have admin privileges so I can't download Drive for Desktop, but I can add network locations. I'm wondering if I can add a Google Drive folder this way? I tried searching for it but all the tutorials ask the user to download some software, and if I could do that I'd just use Drive for desktop... Attached is the error message I'm getting.

I want to be able to sync my files easily so I don't have to keep downloading and re-uploading..

[Error adding network folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHOIp.png)

I can run certain executables, such as [Vivaldi browser executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ksM.png), perhaps because it only downloads it to my profile? Though I am not 100% sure if that is why it lets me open and download it and not other .exe files.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: okay so because this is impossible I requested temporary admin rights to download the software and it was granted so I just downloaded it lmao... bad news for anyone else trying this who can't get admin rights though.

Answer (score 2):

> I can add network locations. I'm wondering if I can add a Google Drive folder this way?

No, not with built-in tools. Windows supports SMB and WebDAV(S) file shares, but Google Drive offers neither of those.

(Some other cloud file hosting systems, such as Nextcloud, *do* offer WebDAVS and could be mapped as a "network location" – assuming everything works as it's supposed to.)

Comment: There is third-party software that mimics WebDAV functionality to use it with Google Drive but software like that is a non-starter due to the fact the author is not an Administrator.

Comment: okay, thank you for the quick response!